# SQL Subquery all data from same table

Tags: sql

I have a table where I would like to have one field (account) always shown then subqueries for counts or sums with criteria.

Example:

```
select  ndhist_acct_nbr,    
    (select count(ndhist_acct_nbr) from dbo.nd_history where ndhist_type = '30' 
      and ndhist_rsn = '0' and ndhist_trcd = 'NF*' and ndhist_ref_type = '0' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013') as NSF_TOTAL,
    (select sum(ndhist_amt) from dbo.nd_history where ndhist_type = '30' 
      and ndhist_rsn = '98' and ndhist_trcd = 'TW0' and ndhist_ref_type = '11' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013') as SIG_SPEND,
    (select count(ndhist_acct_nbr) from dbo.nd_history where ndhist_type = '30' 
      and ndhist_rsn = '23' and ndhist_trcd = 'TW0' and ndhist_ref_type = '11' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013') as PIN_TRANS,
    (select count(ndhist_acct_nbr) from dbo.nd_history where ndhist_type = '30' 
      and ndhist_rsn = '21' and ndhist_trcd = 'SC*' and ndhist_ref_type = '0' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013') as FOREIGN_AMT_FEE
from    dbo.nd_history
group by ndhist_acct_nbr
```

The problem is the results - all of the account numbers show up but the counts/sum fields all repeat the data. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select  ndhist_acct_nbr,    
        count(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '0' and ndhist_trcd = 'NF*' and ndhist_ref_type = '0' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                   then ndhist_acct_nbr end) as NSF_TOTAL,
        sum(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '98' and ndhist_trcd = 'TW0' and ndhist_ref_type = '11' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                 then ndhist_amt end) as SIG_SPEND,
        count(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '23' and ndhist_trcd = 'TW0' and ndhist_ref_type = '11' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                   then ndhist_acct_nbr end) as PIN_TRANS,
        count(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '21' and ndhist_trcd = 'SC*' and ndhist_ref_type = '0' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                   then ndhist_acct_nbr end) as FOREIGN_AMT_FEE
from    dbo.nd_history
group by ndhist_acct_nbr
```

You can use derived columns from the results by putting the whole query inside an inline query and then selecting from it - like so:

```
select sq.*, 
       NSF_TOTAL*5 + SIG_SPEND*0.10 + PIN_TRANS*0.05 + FOREIGN_ATM_FEE as TOTAL_INCOME
from
(select  ndhist_acct_nbr,    
         count(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '0' and ndhist_trcd = 'NF*' and ndhist_ref_type = '0' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                    then ndhist_acct_nbr end) as NSF_TOTAL,
         sum(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '98' and ndhist_trcd = 'TW0' and ndhist_ref_type = '11' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                  then ndhist_amt end) as SIG_SPEND,
         count(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '23' and ndhist_trcd = 'TW0' and ndhist_ref_type = '11' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                    then ndhist_acct_nbr end) as PIN_TRANS,
         count(case when ndhist_type = '30' and ndhist_rsn = '21' and ndhist_trcd = 'SC*' and ndhist_ref_type = '0' and ndhist_dt >= '03/01/2013'
                    then ndhist_acct_nbr end) as FOREIGN_AMT_FEE
 from    dbo.nd_history
 group by ndhist_acct_nbr) sq
```

This could be done more elegantly via a CTE if you are using a RDBMS (such as Oracle, PostgreSQL or SQLServer) that supports CTEs.

Comment: This works perfect - what if I wanted to add one final piece:  A column that creates income (NSF_TOTAL)*5) + ((SIG_SPEND)*0.10%) + ((PIN_TRANS)* $0.05) + ((FOREIGN_ATM_FEE)*$1.00)) as TOTAL_INCOME

Comment: @TomMurphy: I have updated my answer to show how this can be done - at the moment, it is using 10% of SIG_SPEND; if you want 0.1% instead, then change the SIG_SPEND component of TOTAL_INCOME to be `SIG_SPEND*0.001`.

Answer (score 1):

Your subqueries are standalone - they don't depend on `ndhist_acct_nbr` field in any way, so the result is always the same.

Besides, this technique (using this many subqueries for every row of output) is a bad idea.
You should simplify the query, and instead of `count distinct` and subqueries, make `sum(case when ...` clauses.